# In Python: In a list of tuples that represent X, Y points, what is the syntax to access a particular X or Y?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, tuples

For example if

`list = [{0: 1}, {0: 2}, {1: 0}, {1: 2}, {2: 0}, {2: 1}, {2: 2}]`

what is the syntax to get the `x` and `y` of the second item?

```
x = list[1] ?
y = list[1] ?
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Sorry, this is Python.

Comment: Those are not tuples.

Comment: Is this a list of tuples, or a list of dictionaries? The question title says tuples, but the syntax is dictionaries.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to store a 2-dimensional point as a dict `{x: y}` rather than a tuple `(x, y)`.

Comment: Backgrounder: [List vs. tuple vs. set vs. dictionary in Python](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/list-vs-tuple-vs-set-vs-dictionary-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list you have shown is:

```
[{0: 1}, {0: 2}, {1: 0}, {1: 2}, {2: 0}, {2: 1}, {2: 2}]
```

This is a `list` of `dicts`, each with a single element. For the second item (at index 1), the dictionary has one key/value pair with key `0` and value `2`. To access this, you could do this:

```
        myList = [{0: 1}, {0: 2}, {1: 0}, {1: 2}, {2: 0}, {2: 1}, {2: 2}]
        myDict = myList[1]
        key, value = next(iter(myDict.items()))
        print(key, value)
```

If what you want instead is a `list` of `tuples`, that would be something like:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

You could access the second `tuple` in the `list` as follows:

```
        myList = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
        x = myList[1][0]
        y = myList[1][1]
        print(x, y)
```

Alternatively, you could use this more concise assignment syntax:

```
        x, y = myList[1]
```